# Create protected function in base class and receive slots as arguments

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I have created a base and derived class. Both have some common code which differs only in the slots when I have use connect. I intend to create a common function which is protected and takes as an argument the slot function pointer.

```
class Base
{
protected:
    virtual void createcommon(void(*)(int));
    
slots:
    void slotBase(int);
};
    
class Derived
{
slots:
    void slotDerived(int);
}
    
void Base::createcommon(void(*slotPtr)(int))
{
    //some common stuff
    connect(m_comboBox, QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::ACurrentIndexChanged), this, slotPtr);
}
    
void Base::xyz()
{
    createcommon(&Base::slotBase); //does not work, compiler says "argument of type void (Base::*)(int) is incompatible with type void (*)(int).
}
    
void Derived::func()
{
    createcommon(&Derived::slotDerived); //does not work, compiler says "argument of type void (Derived::*)(int) is incompatible with type void (*)(int).
}
```

Is it possible to do so via function pointers?
Otherwise the option left is to create a second virtual function like virtual void initConnect() in both Base and Derived classes to connect appropriately.

Comment: You can't pass a member function to a function pointer, you'll need to use `std:: function` as the argument to `createcommon`. Probably easier just to use a virtual slot though

Comment: Pointer to member function is different from pointer to function. <https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members> You can not create pointer to whatever class member function, need to encapsulate to lambda or std::function..

Comment: `void Base::createcommon(std::function<void(int)> callback)`, and then in xyx use a lambda expression for registration `createcommon([this](int value){ slotBase(value); })` this will capture the this pointer for later use allowing you to call member functions.

Comment: @AlanBirtles passing a std::function is IMO the better solution (loose coupling)

Comment: As pointed, using std::function along with lambda works. Thanks a lot !